# PowerShell 'in' operator and Object[]

Tags: powershell, in-operator

I like to find all disk partitions which resides on an iSCSI Disk using PowerShell.

To find all iSCSI disk object IDs we can use:

```
Get-Disk | Where BusType -ieq iscsi | Select -prop ObjectId
```

Using the `in` operator, this should return all partitions:

```
Get-Partition | Where DiskId in (Get-Disk | Where BusType -ieq iscsi | Select -prop ObjectId)
```

Unfortunately, this command returns a typical PowerShell error:

```
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:1 char:17
+ Get-Partition | Where DiskId in (Get-Disk | Where BusType -ieq iscsi | Select -p ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

How do I use the `in` operator the right way?

Comment: Note that the operator is `-in`, not `in`.

Answer (score 0):

`select -prop ObjectId` does not do what you think. It creates a new object that has a subset of the properties.

Use `select -exp ObjectId` instead. It returns the property-values themselves, without wrapping them in a custom object.

```
Get-Partition | Where DiskId -in (Get-Disk | Where BusType -ieq iscsi | Select -exp ObjectId)
```

Comment: So cooool!, thanks a lot for your explanation and the solution!